# overlay transparency video on top of other video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, alpha-transparency, ffmpeg-php

I have two videos. I used below command to overlay first video(overlay.mp4) on top of second video(main.mp4) and set transparency for alpha chanel to 0.3

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i main.mp4 \
-i overlay.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
[1]format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.3,setpts=PTS+8/TB[1d]; \
[0][1d]overlay=enable='between(t,8, 13)'[v1]; \
-map [v1] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

The result looks like this. 
[image: overlay]

The background of first video is still remaining (look darker than the main video background).

I want to overlay only the 'foreground' on top of second video.
How to set transparency of overlay video background so only the foreground display?

**Edit**

Set the colorkey option and it works

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i main.mp4 \
-i overlay.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
[1]format=rgb24,colorkey=black:0.3:0.2,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.3,setpts=PTS+8/TB[1d]; \
[0][1d]overlay=enable='between(t,8, 13)'[v1]; \
-map [v1] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a keying filter to remove the background color

```
ffmpeg -y \
-i main.mp4 \
-i overlay.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
[1]format=rgb24,colorkey=black,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.3,setpts=PTS+8/TB[1d]; \
[0][1d]overlay=enable='between(t,8, 13)'[v1]; \
-map [v1] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Comment: I set the similarity and blend value for colorkey option: `colorkey=black:0.3:0.2` and It works!
Thank you